# Error when spliting character vector in two variables

Tags: r, csv, split

I am trying to split a character variable into different variables in this way:

```
df <- data.frame('Z' = c(1,2), 'var'= c('01*02*03','01*02'))
> df
  Z      var
1 1 01*02*03
2 2    01*02
```

However, when I try to use separate_rows from tidyverse the following error comes up:

```
df <- df %>% separate_rows(var,"*")
Error in `separate_rows()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `*` doesn't exist.
```

This is not specific to the function separate_rows (I think) as it happens in any other function, I think the problem is with the character '*' but I don't know why.

Any help would be appreciated.

KR
Ruben

Comment: Use `df %>% separate_rows(var, sep = "\\*")` or just `df %>% separate_rows(var)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df |>
  tidyr::separate_rows(var, sep = "\\*")
```

The ellipsis argument of `separate_rows` captures any non-named arguments and assumes these are columns you want to split into rows. This is why you can just pass `var` unnamed because that is the variable you want to separate.